How to check if $j->{component} is empty in perl?
This doesn't seem to work for me, and can't figure out how to make it work. The system that takes the json I'm creating with this doesn't like "components": null,
if ($s->{category} == ""){
    $j->{components} = "Unspecified";
  }
   else
  {
    j->{components} = $s->{category};
  }

Thanks

"Doesn't work" is a very poor description of a problem. I have a car that doesn't work, can you tell me what's wrong with it? Be more specific.

Assigning empty string is still assigning something. If you want to know if a hash array does not have a specified key, you can use defined() function. And if you want to destroy an assignment - use undef
#!/usr/bin/perl
my $j = {};

$j->{var1} = 1;
print $j->{var1}, "\n";

print "has var1\n" if (defined($j->{var1}));
print "does not have var2\n" if (! defined($j->{var2}));

undef $j->{var1};
print "does not have var1\n" if (! defined($j->{var1}));


Sorry I have formed my question wrong, I have a 400mbyte text file containing data that I parse, and when I'm converting the file to another format, I'd like to have $j->{components} being - for example - "Undefined" if $s->{category} doesn't exist. But now that i wrote down my question more precisely, the solution is quite simple: if (!($s->{category})){ Thank you for opening my eyes :)

@Nash ! exists $h->{key} is not the same as ! $h->{key}, nor are either the same as ! defined $h->{key}. I recommend doing some testing.

This answer is very poor. It's extremely hard to read, has print statements that have nothing to do with the variable in question, uses non-descriptive variable names (eg var1, var2), and although I wouldn't normally complain about this in a simple example, the shebang line is present so use warnings; and use strict; should be present.

In my case in the old system, if they didn't set the field to something, it got set to "Unspecified" however, when exporting the data to JSON, the "category" was not empty, but wasn't there at all. So if there is 0 times "category": "", but if it's "Unspecified" in the old system, then there's no "category": line in a given 'block' at all. So my solution was to use the ! as above because the new system's JSON importer crashes if there's no "components" line in a 'block'. Thank you everyone. Sorry for my poor terminology.


exists( $h->{ k } ) checks for existence in a hash.
defined( $h->{ k } ) checks if defined.
$h->{ k } checks if true.
== is used to compare defined values as numbers.
eq is used to compare defined values as strings.
Always use use warnings; or equivalent.





exists( $h->{ k } )
defined( $h->{ k } )
$h->{ k }




{}
false
false
false


{"k":null}
true
false
false


{"k":""}{"k":0}{"k":"0"}
true
true
false


{"k":"abc"}{"k":"123"}{"k":"00"}
true
true
true




Depending of what is meant by "doesn't exist", there are different answers.
!$s->{category} being true means:

the key category does not exist in $s, or
the key category exists in $s but $s->{category} is undef, or
the key category exists in $s, $s->{category} is not undef but evaluates to false.

One can check the first condition via exists.

Note that the question doesn't actually say "doesn't exist".

@TLP, it refers to OP's comment to their accepted answer.

I see. Well, remember that comments can and do get deleted. It can be a good idea to be specific.
